# Spring REST Basic Authentication Design Approach

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, authentication

**Environment :**

Spring 4

Spring Security 4

Spring MVC 4

Hibernate 4

MySQL

**Issue :**

Below is the requirement :

1)We are developing a Spring REST service for inventory management.

2)This web service will be consumed by .NET client. (or may be mobile device in future)

3)The users of REST service need to be authenticated. The user will use login form displayed by .NET client and if authentication is successfull , he will be 
allowed to consume REST API.

4)If authentication fails , user won't be allowed entry into REST service.

Now we have decided to use Basic Authentication for this.

My question is : How do we achieve this using Spring MVC REST and Spring security ?

Below is my first attempt :

application-security.xml

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"> 
       <intercept-url pattern="/usermanagement/authenticate" access="permitAll"/>
       <intercept-url pattern="/abhishek/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
       <http-basic/>
       <csrf disabled="true"/> 
    </http>

   <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="Atul" password="12345" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
   </authentication-manager>
```

Following is the flow happening right now :

1)The /authentication API looks up user in Db and returns Http Status code 201(success ) or 401 (failure) accordingly. (this url is unsecured)

2)If success , client puts username/password as Authorization header (which is used in login) and sends this header for future Http requests.

3)Now once next request comes (this is secured), spring security  comes into picture and again authentication happens here. 
But this time it will be Spring provided.

4)So there are two authentication mechanism are being used .

5)I know I am messing up here , but not able to decide on what is the correct approach to design this.

6)How can client be provided the authentication capability by hooking into Spring security ? He needs to know authentication success/failure 
immediately after he logs in.

Please help since I am struggling a lot on this.

Comment: Why not token based authentication?

Comment: I'd recommend Spring Session for this